# How to stop data shuffling while training the HuggingFace BERT model?

Tags: nlp, huggingface-transformers, bert-language-model, transformer-model

I want to train a BERT transformer model using the `HuggingFace` implementation/library. During training, `HuggingFace` shuffles the training data for each epoch, but I don't want to shuffle the data. For example, if I have 5 training data and the batch size = 2, then I want the training data to be presented as [1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4] and [4, 5]. I cannot find any resources that show how to disable the default shuffling.

Answer (score 3):

Generally, it is considered good practice to randomise the presentation order of training data for each epoch. If using batches, then this also includes randomly sampling your training data to create the batches. Doing so ensures that the data for each training iteration is [independently and identically distributed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independent_and_identically_distributed_random_variables) (i.i.d.) from the previous, which will lead to improved overall performance. If the order of training data is maintained between epochs, then the model will develop a disposition for the particular order presented and will likely not perform well in other circumstances.

For this reason, HuggingFace will not implement the ability to switch off shuffling for the data loader. You can see that it was requested [here](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/issues/11693) on their GitHub and denied with the recommendation that if such a feature was desired, then one should override and subclass `get_train_dataloader` to return a training data loader that doesn't use a sampler or `shuffle=True`.

Comment: Random sampling is iid. Random shuffling isn't technically iid because each batch is dependent on the previous. If the strategy were truly iid, there would be a chance of seeing the same item in consecutive batches, or even multiple times within the same batch.

Comment: @jxmorris12 Batches would be dependent on each other if the sampling method used to create a batch was dependent on other batches. In the OP's example, sequentially sampling an ordered set would obviously result in dependent batches, hence, I agree that randomly shuffling these batches would not result in true iid data being presented to the model. Instead, batches must be created through random sampling, and then the batches randomly shuffled for each epoch. I believe we both have the same understanding of what constitutes an iid strategy here? I'll update my answer to make this point clear